# mongoose findOneAndUpdate conditional update based on document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When a user goes through SSO (like google login), I want to find or create that user, and only set a new sessionId if it's blank.

So if it's a returning user, that has sessionId, I don't want to change that.
if it doesn't have sessionId, I want to create it.

Pseudo code:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, 
  { 
     ...data, 
     sessionId: userSessionId ? userSessionId : genSessionId()
  }
)
```

Is that possible in a single DB call?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that in the `filter` itself:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    ...query, // Your current filter 
    userSessionId: { $exists: false }
  }, 
  { 
     ...data, 
     sessionId: userSessionId ? userSessionId : genSessionId()
  }
)
```

This way, if user already has `userSessionId` property, the query will not update it.

Comment: I still want to update the other data on the user, and also get the user document back